# const existingSocial = await social.findOne({ username }); returns existingSocial as null but then too it doesnt goes into the else part

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mern, mongoose-schema

so here is my whole code:

```
router.route('/add').post(async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    const { username, facebook, twitter, instagram } = req.body;
    try {
        const existingUser = await User.findOne({ username }); //bcoz implementing update functionality directly inside adding page

        console.log(username);
        if (existingUser) {
            const existingSocial = await social.findOne({ username });
            console.log(existingSocial);
            if (existingSocial) {
               
                let result = await social.findByIdAndUpdate(existingSocial._id, req.body)
                if (result) {
                    console.log(existingSocial);
                   
                    const userIndex = existingUser.connections.findIndex(id => id.equals(existingSocial._id));
                    existingUser.connections[userIndex] = existingSocial._id;
                    await existingUser.save();

                    res.status(200).send({ message: "Social Updated till end" })
                    // res.status(200).send({ message: "Social Updated!" })
                } else {
                    console.log("line 36");
                    res.status(400).send({ message: "Error: " + err })
                }
            }
            else {
                const newSocial = new social(req.body);
                await newSocial.save()

                console.log(newSocial);
               
                existingUser.connections.push(newSocial);
                await existingUser.save();

                res.status(200).send({ message: "Social Added and User updated!" })
            }
        }
        else {
            console.log("Line 59");
            res.status(400).send({ message: "User not found for username: " + username })
        }

    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).send({ message: "Internal Server Error: " + error })
    }
});
```

so the console log of existingSocial right after the await social.findOne({username}); function returns the null value so it should go inside the else part where I am adding a new entry into the socials table which is done through:
`const newSocial = new social(req.body);  await newSocial.save()`
but the problem is that it doesn't enters the else part and doesn't adds the new social.

and the error I am being shown is the status 500 error.

Comment: What is the error you get on the server?

Comment: Change the last catch to read `catch (error) { console.log(error); res.status(500).send({ message: "Internal Server Error: " + error })}`. Then you will be able to see the problem. It is likely the `await newSocial.save()` or `await existingUser.save();` is failing.